# how to change the png file background to transparent

Tags: macos, png, image-editing, transparency

I used Paintbrush drawing an icon, if it is on a colored background, it will display a white block shown as below.

[image: Image without transparent background]

I prefer to change the icon background from white color to transparent color:

[image: Image as it should look like]

Do I need a special tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) for all my graphics editing needs. It makes it trivial to make a png with transparency. If you do a lot of graphics, or even just playing around it is worth the download. Also, it's free.

Comment: Thanks. But I am useing mac os x 10.5.8, there is no version of GIMP for it.

Comment: @user36089: No, there area packages available: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html

Answer (score 8):

You can actually do that using [Paintbrush (Mac)](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/)

Select a foreground color - any color will do as our intention is to remove the background.

[image: Select foreground color in Paintbrush]

Next, drag the **opacity** slider from 100% to 0%. You should see your selected color turn into a grayish tone.

[image: Remove Opacity to 0%]

Now click the **fill** icon and click anywhere in the background.

[image: Fill the background with transparent color]

You should see the background is now transparent.

[image: Background of image is now transparent]

Comment: had to fill multiple times - no shadows. still more helpful though

Answer (score 5):

No installation needed - use Preview.

1. Open the image in preview
2. Click the "toolcase" icon in the toolbar
3. Select the "magic wand" tool
4. Click and drag to set the "radius" until it selects what you want to get rid of
5. Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
6. Rinse and repeat for other areas as you would with fill

This is a late answer, but this is much simpler than any of the other answers. For the googlers!

Comment: yes it used to work, but for some reason the picture has a black background when you export as PNG

Comment: The wand doesn't seem to be available anymore.